# Size of structures in .NET

Tags: .net, interop, struct

My problem is to send a structure between a program in C to a C# program.

I made a structure in C#:

```
public struct NetPoint {
    public float lat; // 4 bytes
    public float lon; // 4 bytes
    public int alt; // 4 bytes
    public long time; // 8 bytes
}
```

The total size of the structure must be 20 bytes.

When I do a `sizeof()` in C++ of this structure,

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
    "SizeOf(NetPoint) = " +
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(new NetPoint()));
```

the debug console shows:

> SizeOf(NetPoint) = 24

But I expected to have 20 bytes. Why do I see a difference?

Comment: See here: http://www.vsj.co.uk/articles/display.asp?id=501

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, technically the structure must be a ***minimum*** of 20 bytes. If you allocate more when sending, the receiver just won't use / copy them. The problem is always underallocation.

That said, I see the problem. Hmm. I think the problem is the last long.... which IMHO gets aligned to eight bytes, injecting four empty bytes before. I think there is a performance penalty for having an eight-byte element not aligned to an eight-byte boundary.

Attach [StructLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) attributes to determine the offset of every element manually. Then you should be able to get things in line.

Reference: *[How to control the physical layout of the data fields in the .NET Framework 2.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922785)*

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct NetPoint {  
    public float lat; // 4 bytes 
    public float lon; // 4 bytes 
    public int alt; // 4 bytes 
    public long time; // 8 bytes 
}
```

That at least should align elements to a one-byte boundary. You can go further by defining the exact start of every element, too, if needed.

Comment: Your solution works too. Thank you very much. Your solution seems to be easier than John's answer. I will use your solution.. Bye

Answer (score 10):

As a general rule, CPUs like to have variables aligned in memory at a location that is an even multiple of their size, so a four-byte integer should be on a memory address that is divisible by four, and an eight-byte `long` should be at an address divisible by eight.

The C# (and C++) language designers know this, and they will insert padding in structures to provide the necessary alignment. So the actual layout of your structure looks like this:

```
public struct NetPoint {
    public float lat;          // 4 bytes   Offset  0
    public float lon;          // 4 bytes   Offset  4
    public int alt;            // 4 bytes   Offset  8
    int to_preserve_alignment; // 4 bytes   Offset 12
    public long time;          // 8 bytes   Offset 16
}
```

You can fix this by making the long the first value, as a rule, if you always put the largest values at the beginning of your structures, you won't have any padding inserted to preserve alignment of members.

You can also fix it by adding

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
```

before the structure declaration, but that will result in mis-aligned `long time` which hurts performance. On some CPUs it hurts performance quite a lot. (The [ALPHA AXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Alpha) would fault on misaligned members, for instance). [x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) CPUs have only a minor performance penalty, but there is a danger of future CPUs having a major performance penalty, so it's best to design your structures to align properly (rather than packing them) if you can.

Comment: Wow, I love this type of feedback.  I just learned something new and interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the attribute [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)] and see what happens. I suspect an 8 byte padding, so it's 3x8 bytes.

Comment: no, object in .net (except for primitives like int) have size more than sum of fields.

Answer (score 1):

TomTom answered this question pretty well I think, but there is another alternative if you end up in a tricky COM interop struct situation.  Each field can be aligned on its own using FieldOffset attributes.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct COMPoint
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public int X;
    [FieldOffset(4)] public int Y;
}
```